# Elasticsearch query that looks into object and compares certain elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just started with Elasticsearch. I have a document of this kind:

```
{
  arr: {
    "01": "one phrase",
    "02": "another",
    "03": 900
  },
  field1: "val1",
  field2: "val2"
}
```

What should be a query that finds all documents where the second element in the `arr` field starts with "ano", and where the third field is in the range of 800 - 1000?

If it is too inefficient, I am currently free to change this "schema" to something different.

I have read about the nested objects but at this stage fail to understand if I have to explicitly command Elasticsearch to index the `arr` field internals. If I have, I would appreciate an example of the create index command with some sort of "if exist", because the app will try to create this index every time it starts up.

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share your es mapping

Comment: @torzonhot I don't know what it is... I've read about removing mapping types and didn't bother to create a mapping. Is it a step of defining index? Then it's part of my question as well. Thank you!

Comment: As for field types, in the arr object there are two strings and an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the mapping by visiting this url

```
http://localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX_NAME_HERE/_mapping
```

If you didn't specify the mapping before inserting an entry, then elasticsearch handled it by creating it for you. Check here for more
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

I expect it to be something like this

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "arr": {
            "properties": {
              "01": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "02": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "03": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "field1": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "field2": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

And here is the query if my assumption about your mapping is correct

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "arr.02": {
              "value": "ano*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "arr.03": {
              "gte": 800,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Be warned, the range query is inclusive, meaning `800<=x<=1000`. If you want it exclusive, meaning `800<x<1000` then change the query to `gt` and `lt` respectively.

Comment: Thank you! But... does it mean that the `arr` needs to adhere that schema? I was hoping to be free in number and types of it's fields; the query should determine what documents will be filtered out, if the types mismatch.

Say, if "03" is a string, such document would be excluded, but another query where "03" is expected to be a string will catch it.

Have to admit the whole notion of mapping is over my head for now for the "schemaless" nosql store

Comment: It can be schemaless, but if you need to do specific queries, it has to have a structure. Yes what you described is more complex. You need to add some structure if you want complex search capabilities

Comment: thanks, can you please advise how do I add that structure? My problem is that I even can't ask correct question on my level of knowledge, sorry for that

Comment: No problem. I've already included the link that will help you. Read about the elasticsearch mapping functionality.